# Is SDHC Card compatible with a MBP mid-2009?

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, sd-card

I have a Mac Book Pro, mid-2009 model that has a SD card slot.
I just bought a SD Card from SanDisk, 8gb, SDHC.

When I insert the SD card in the slot, it is recognized by the MBP: I have a new icon on the desktop, `NO NAME`, and the disk utility tool shows me the information related to the disk and displays a correct volume size (around 7.95Gb).

In the Disk Utility Tool, when I click on disk verification, I get the following information:

```
Vérification du volume « NO NAME »Vérification du système de fichiers** /dev/disk1s1
** Phase 1 - Preparing FAT
** Phase 2 - Checking Directories
** Phase 3 - Checking for Orphan Clusters
Free space in FSInfo block (-1) not correct (242303)
Fix? no
0 files, 7753696 KiB free (242303 clusters)
```

Unfortunately, the Disk Utility Tool does not allow me to format the SD card.

The purpose of this SD Card is to use it to boot a Raspberry Pi. So I downloaded their utility `SDFormatter`. This utility recognizes the SD Card, but when I try to format it, it tells me that it is write protected.

Of course, the physical lock on the SD card itself is on the correct position!

So my question: is my old MBP compatible with this kind of SD Card?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems your not the only one. Maybe try some of the solutions here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3275447?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Thanks @KevinGrabher I will have a look on these discussions.

Comment: Unfortunately, my problem persists. I don't have the exact same issue as on these discussions. They don't succeed to mount the SD Card. I can, but it's on a read-only mode, and I can't format it to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally seems that my MBP is incompatible with this SD card format or size.

I bought a multi-cards reader, and it works.

Note that the exact same behavior on a 2010 MBP.